# JavaScript: Accessing call-site local variables from remote function

Tags: javascript, scope, eval

I'm not sure if its possible, but firstly, for clarification, an example of what I'm hoping to accomplish.

Take the `eval` function for instance, you can write something such as the following:

```
(function() {
   let a = 1;
   let b = 2;
   return eval('a + b') // returns 3
})()
```

So the above code at first glance is quite simply. But when you break it down, you'll see there is actually a bit more going on here.

The behavior seen in the above example that I'm most interested in is, `a` and `b` are both defined locally, `eval` is than called with a string argument.

For demonstration sake, lets pretend the implementation of eval is something like:

```
function eval(string) {
   //Magic
   return result
}
```

So when eval is called, `a` and `b` should be undefined as the functions scope for eval differs from that of the original call site.

To prove this point, if we try and create a simple wrapper for `eval` like so:

```
function eval_wrapper(str) {
    return eval(str)
}
```

and call the original sample code with `eval_wrapper` in place of `eval`:

```
(function() {
   let a = 1;
   let b = 2;
   return eval_wrapper('a + b') // throws 'a is not defined' error
})()
```

You'll see that we get the error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined`

So my question is, how does `eval` access local variables, and can we write some code that would allow `eval_wrapper` to execute without error by accessing the call-site scope somehow.

Comment: I doubt it's possible (at least not in any reliable and sane manner), that would break standard lexical scoping rules

Comment: `eval` is NOT a function written in javascript - so, javascript scoping rules don't apply

Comment: since it is just a function, pass a and b along with the string?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss for my use case, I don't want to modify the call or the call site, just the `eval` function name with my wrapped one.

Answer (score 0):

define it in the same scope perhaps?

```js
(function() {
  function eval_wrapper(str) {
    return eval(str)
  }
  let a = 1;
  let b = 2;
  let c = eval_wrapper('a + b') // throws 'a is not defined' error
  console.log(c);
})()
```

Comment: The behavior Im looking for is specifically the fact eval can execute from outside of the scope while still having access to the variables at the call site. The above just avoids the behavior.